# Can't remove requirement for SSL from Freenode channel

Tags: ssl, irc

I set up a private invite-only channel on Freenode for my organization. I then set it to require SSL using `/mode #channelname +z` . I now need to remove the SSL requirement. When I type `/mode #channelname -z` it responds `myusername sets mode -z #mychannelname`. However, when I try to log in without SSL, it still says SSL is required. I've checked the available documentation and can't find any other way to change this.

Answer (score 0):

I asked on #freenode and was told that the proper command is `/mode #channelname -S`. This successfully removed the SSL requirement.

`-S` is listed elsewhere as the command to strip color codes, so I guess Freenode is nonstandard here.